# What is an acceptable geocoding score?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geocoding, arcgis-rest-api

I've been searching on how an address score is calculated, but didn't find anything that clearly defines how the score is calculated. So what score value is acceptable to assume that a result is close enough to input address?

Comment: what are your requirements building footprint or parcel, street or town?

Comment: Street, number, state and country

Comment: so you are looking for a score of above 70 (out of 100) https://geonet.esri.com/message/494638#494638

Comment: The ESRI content linked above is cross-posted here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/84547/how-are-geocoding-scores-calculated-in-arcgis/142193#142193